# how to have more than one JToolBar in one screen?

Tags: java, swing

How to put more than one JToolBar on one screen and allow them floating. Usually we put JToolBar on a container with BorderLayout. if we put all JToolBars on a panel then put the panel to the container, we will have problem to allow them floating. any ideas?

Comment: Works fine for me. Post your SSCCE: http://sscce.org

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Instead of toolbar have a panel. This panel should have a flow layout. Then start adding toolbars to it. Toolbar is floating by default, so you should be able to move it around.